# How to display Selected Video thumbnail in phonegap android?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to `phonegap`.

My requirement is when user click on a button. gallery should open and display the selected video thumbnail.

I open the gallary  by using following code.

```
function getvideo() 
     {
     navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessvideo, onFailurevideo, {
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO
           });
```

i get the url which one is selected.

I want to display the selected video through thumbnail.

If any one know please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Looking for this exact same thing as well. The only thing I have come across is calling FFMpeg from within PHP as part of the upload process. Next steps would then be to update an img src from within javascript with the generated image. Seems like a bit of a long winded process for something that should be covered by the Cordova API

Comment: I have also found this plugin (although not tested it)

http://plugreg.com/plugin/ednasgoldfishuk/VideoThumbnail

Seems to only support iOS though

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use HTML5 Tag  to view and play video.
You have to Verify your browser or version of Android/Ios to know if it support html5.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp